# Select specific value from list class

Tags: c#, list

I have the following list class

```
public class Users
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string PlayerID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I was wondering how do I select the playerID where username = x ?

Comment: That's not a list class. That's a class which would more sensibly be called `User`, and the automatically implemented properties could very easily be written on a single line. Now, assuming you really have a list of these values, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var player = playerList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Username == "x");
if(player != null)
{
    string id = player.PlayerID;
}
```